# How to select specific video files to upload to gallery in Android Q?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentresolver, mediastore, scoped-storage

Having recorded a video using mediaRecorder and Camera API, I am trying to save the video to the user's gallery (either by saving to their external movies, DCIM directory, or other).

Unfortunately, the code I've found from the docs or StackOverflow seem to create their respective URIs without any reference to the recorded video or the file in which its kept. Specifically, the code I attempted to use is:

```
String videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

    ContentValues valuesvideos;
    valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + "Folder");
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);

    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;

    try {
        pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo,"w");

        assert pfd != null;
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

// Get the already saved video as fileinputstream from here
            File storageDir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Folder");
            File imageFile = new File(storageDir, "testStorage");

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);


            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {

                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            pfd.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The code and answers around it seem to imply that by accessing the MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY the resolver can access the saved video file but I see no explicit reference to it. Prior to recording the video, I define the file assigned to mediaRecorder as such:

```
static File getMediaFile(Context c) {

    File mediaStorageDir = c.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

}
```

Upon stopping the video I get this error (referencing this line: `Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);`):

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external_primary/video/media at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java.167) ...

How do I create a URI properly and with reference to the saved video? Substituting the URI from file `Uri.fromFile(f);` in place of uriSavedVideo doesn't work either.

Comment: `Uri uriSavedVideo` is the reference. The uri you want and need for future access.

Comment: Are you doing and update() with IS_PENDING == 0 at the end?

Comment: The subject of your post is pretty strange.

Comment: @blackapps `Uri uriSavedVideo` still doesn't seem to refer to the file (from getMediaFile) where the video is kept, could you elaborate?

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate. If you wanna read the file for instance opening an inputstream than use that uri. Your getMediaFile function is about the source file which you copied. The copy is in the obtained uri. You have two files now and they have nothing to do with each other. Your video is now kept in two places. I would delete the first one as storage will fill up quickly.

Comment: Replacing `MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY` with the absolute path of the file still has the same error. At this point I think I have too many misconceptions to ask a good question. Really what I'm trying to find out is how to save a video file to gallery in Android Q, with existing solutions incomplete for my case.

Comment: You already did that. Your code is ok. I dont understand what would be wrong. Abour which error are you talking?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the _PRIMARY. Are you on Android Q?

Comment: Not quite; the the current code is getting the UnsupportedOperationException as detailed above. Any ideas as to what may be causing it?

Comment: Is your problem only copying that file? Than please change the subject of your post as it is not to the point. And remove that getMediaFile function as it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @blackapps that's a good point; the device with which I am currently testing is not running Android Q, but 7.1.1 - I shall send it to a phone running Android Q and test accordingly. I hadn't realised how many versions outdated my current testing phone is

Comment: You cannot use RELATIVE_PATH and IS_PENDING below Q. Use DATA instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a specific video file to gallery, I passed the file as a parameter to `new FileInputStream`.

Secondly, as the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) state:

> Only your app can view the file until your app changes the value of IS_PENDING back to 0.

So in keeping with user @blackapps' advice, I manually changed that state. The changed code is below:

```
private static void addToApi29Gallery(File file, Context context) {
    String videoFileName = "video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

    ContentValues valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + "Trickshott");
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);

    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    
    Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY); //all video files on primary external storage
    Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);

    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;

    try {
        pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo,"w");

        assert pfd != null;
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

        // Get the already saved video as fileinputstream from here.
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        
        out.close();
        in.close();
        pfd.close();
        
        valuesvideos.clear(); 
        valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0); // Only your app can see the files until pending is turned into 0.

        context.getContentResolver().update(uriSavedVideo, valuesvideos, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) a habit.